# How to implement thread comment in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-sets

I want to develop a thread comment list like this: http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/gbmg3/ama_request_a_jersey_shore_cameraman/

Is there any opensource gem for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple. I prefer to use `nested_sets`. Check out this [awesome_nested_set GEM](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set). Some folks like [acts_as_tree GEM](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree). But nested_sets fits better your problem.